# Apply animation before widget is removed

Tags: flutter, animation, widget, show-hide

Simple show-hide animation:

```
class ShowHide extends StatelessWidget {
  final double delay;
  final Widget child;
  final double duration;
  final bool isShow;
  ShowHide({
    this.delay = 1,
    this.duration = 1,
    this.child,
    this.isShow = true,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final tween = MultiTween<AniProps>()
      ..add(AniProps.scale, Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0),
          Duration(milliseconds: (500 * duration).round()), Curves.linear);

    return CustomAnimation<MultiTweenValues<AniProps>>(
      delay: Duration(milliseconds: (200 * delay).round()),
      control: isShow
          ? CustomAnimationControl.PLAY
          : CustomAnimationControl.PLAY_REVERSE,
      duration: tween.duration,
      tween: tween,
      child: child,
      builder: (context, child, animation) => Transform.scale(
        scale: animation.get(AniProps.scale),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: child,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My top level widget displays list of picture thumbnails:

```
Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Form(
          key: widget.addEventFormKey,
          onChanged: () {},
          child: Expanded(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: [
                  
                  Visibility(
                    child: AttachmentsListWidget(
                      items: _attachments,
                      onAttachmentDeleted: (String attachment) {
                        setState(() {
                          File(attachment).delete();
                          _attachments.remove(attachment);
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                    visible: _attachments.length > 0,
                 
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

`AttachmentsListWidget` is stateless list of image thumbnails:

```
class AttachmentsListWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const AttachmentsListWidget({
    Key key,
    @required this.items,
    @required this.onAttachmentDeleted,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final List<String> items;
  final Function(String) onAttachmentDeleted;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var _thumbnailsScrollController = ScrollController();
    final thumbnails = <Widget>[];
    Widget thumbnailsWidget;

    if (items.length > 0) {
      for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        thumbnails.add(
          AttachmentWidget(
            attachment: items[i],
            onDeleteClicked: (String attachment) => onAttachmentDeleted(attachment),
          ),
        );
      }
      thumbnailsWidget = Container(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Scrollbar(
              isAlwaysShown: true,
              controller: _thumbnailsScrollController,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                controller: _thumbnailsScrollController,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                child: Row(
                  children: thumbnails,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    } else {
      thumbnailsWidget = Container();
    }
    return thumbnailsWidget;
  }
}
```

That's not any problem to apply animation on show new thumbnail - I need to to surround my `AttachmentWidget` with `ShowHide`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        thumbnails.add(
          ShowHide(
            child: AttachmentWidget(
              attachment: items[i],
              onDeleteClicked: (String attachment) => onAttachmentDeleted(attachment),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
```

But I'm not sure how to apply animation before thumbnail is removed. When removing thumbnail from list, entire widget is reconstructed and new attachment list is applied. So, there will be no any animation applied for single thumbnail removal.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Did you try AnimatedList? This seems the exact use case for it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZtfItHwFlZ8

Comment: I can't use list, because I will be forced to provide height, which depennds from image size.